# Suppression State Error CS0266 When Selecting Data From Database Using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Index view that shows a list of tenants and it works great. I added a small form to the index view to take in and pass a query string to the index method of my Tenants controller. As you can see, I have an If statement that checks to see if the query string is empty. If it is not empty, it goes in and grabs a tenant that has a first name that contains characters of the query string. Well, it is at this point I am receiving an error. I believe it has something to do with the way I am using the ICollection of Tenants in the ApplicatonUser Model or the way I am first loading the tenants that correspond to the logged in user into the tenants variable. I have added all my info below to help diagnose the issue.

Error Message

> Suppression State Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) mentorient

My Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<mentorient.Models.Tenant>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<nav>
    <hr/>
        <a asp-controller="Tenants" asp-action="New">New Tenant</a>
    <hr/>
</nav>
@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <strong>Hold Up!</strong> You do not have any tenants yet.
    </div>
}
else
{
    <form>
        <p>
            Name: <input type="text" name="SearchString"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Filter"/>
        </p>
    </form>

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var tenant in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@tenant.Id</td>
                <td>@tenant.FirstName  @tenant.LastName</td>    
                <td><a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@tenant.Id">Delete</a> | <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@tenant.Id">Details</a></td>
            </tr>

        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

The Index method of the tenant controller that is accepting the query string:

```
 public IActionResult Index(string searchString)
        {
            var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            var tenants = _context.Users.Include(usr => usr.Tenants)
                .Single(usr => usr.Id == userId)
                .Tenants;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                tenants = tenants.Where(t => t.FirstName.Contains(searchString)); // this is where I am getting my error.
            }

            return View(tenants);
        }
```

Here is the Tenant Model:

```
namespace mentorient.Models
{
    public class Tenant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Phone]
        public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My ApplicationUser Model:

```
namespace mentorient.Models
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class


      public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {
            public virtual ICollection<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
                = new List<Tenant>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `.ToList()` at end of your query to select tenant list,

```
tenants.Where(t => t.FirstName.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
```