# Asp.net Core 2 Listing users with their roles

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am now struggling .net Core 2 too long to essentially do an apparantly simple thing: Create a list of a User with its multiple roles.

I have a straightfoward Startup, ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole based on a published example (IdentitySampleApplication; thanks to the creator). The original code creates a SelectList with All roles. I would like to create a SelectList with UserRoles (Roles the user is assigned to). Below is the original code.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager;

    public UserController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(string id)
    {
        EditUserViewModel model = new EditUserViewModel();
        model.ApplicationRoles = roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = r.Name,
            Value = r.Id
        }).ToList();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (user != null)
            {
                model.Name = user.Name;
                model.Email = user.Email;
                model.ApplicationRoleId = roleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.Single()).Id;
            }
        }
        return PartialView("_EditUser", model);
```

I thought to change the code to the following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(string id)
{
    EditUserViewModel model = new EditUserViewModel();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (user != null)
        {
            model.Name = user.Name;
            model.Email = user.Email;
            model.ApplicationRoles = userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        }
    }
```

The EditUserViewModel is

```
public class EditUserViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public string ApplicationRoleId { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting type conversion errors (`cannot implicitly convert System.Threading.....IList<string> to System.Collections.....Rendering.SelectListItem`), which I cannot resolve. I am obviously not on the right track, but cannot think of other solutions.

I would be very thankful for someone to provide a practical solution.

Comment: this is a possible duplicate of the question i asked the other day https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237029/suppression-state-error-cs0266-when-selecting-data-from-database-using-linq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppression State Error CS0266 When Selecting Data From Database Using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237029/suppression-state-error-cs0266-when-selecting-data-from-database-using-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user3688584 I have created the solutions! The following code creates a SelectList with only the assigned roles

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UsList(string id)
    {
        EditUserViewModel model = new EditUserViewModel();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var usr = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                model.Name = user.Name;
                model.Email = user.Email;
                model.ApplicationRoles = usr.Select(u => new SelectListItem() {Text = u}).ToList();
            }

        }
        return View("_UsList", model);
    }
```

Adding a `.ToList()`to the previous answer did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Because you assigned a `List<string>` to a `List<SelectListItem>` property, you must create a new `List<SelectListItem>` from `List<string>` with Select method in LINQ ex: userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Select(u=> new SelectListItem() {Text=u});

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! When applying your suggestion I get an error (red squiglies under Select) `Task<IList<string>> does not contain a definition for 'Select'`

Comment: If have await keyword, `Task<List<string>>` is not available, you can check again or use ToList method before Select